# How to stop NLTK stemmer from removing the trailing "e"?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK stemmer to remove grammatical variations of a stem word.
However, the Port or Snowball stemmers remove the trailing "e" of the original form of a noun or verb, e.g., Profile becomes Profil.

How can I prevent this from happening? I know I can use a conditional to guard against this. But obviously it will fail on different cases.

Is there an option or another API for what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with Philip that the goal of stemmer is to retain only the stem. For this particular case you can try a lemmatizer instead of stemmer which will supposedly retain more of a word and is meant to remove exactly different forms of a word like 'profiles' --> 'profile'. There is a class in NLTK for this - try WordNetLemmatizer() from nltk.stem.

Beware that it's still not perfect (like nothing when working with text) because I used to get 'physic' from 'physics'.

Comment: Didn't see your comment earlier. Thank you. I will accept your answer since it gives more caveats than alvas'.

Comment: I forgot about lemmatization! Now I feel silly haha.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Stemming "joking", "gaming", and "coming" all retains the "e".

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer, PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> word = 'profile'
>>> porter.stem(word)
'profil'
>>> wnl.lemmatize(word)
'profile'
>>> wnl.lemmatize(word) if wnl.lemmatize(word).endswith('e') else porter.stem(word)
'profile'
```

Comment: Woohoo. That's convenient. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The goal of a stemmer is to remove as much of the word as possible to allow it to cover as many cases as possible, yet retain the core of the word. One reason profile might go to profil is to cover the case of profiling. You would need a conditional or another stemmer in order to guard against this, although I would imagine the majority of them will remove the trailing 'e'. (Especially giving the number of 'e' -> 'ing' cases)

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, but couldn't there be a switch to specify "let's output the noun of this series"?

Comment: I guess I'm just confused about why you're using a stemmer for the approach. If you're just looking to find nouns, you could use a part-of-speech tagger and only log singular nouns. Is that more of your use? If not, could you specify?