# PorterStemmer() trims the last word in a sentence differently

Tags: python, nltk, porter-stemmer

I have the following code for an off-line environment:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

test = {'grams':  ['First value because one does two THREE', 'Second value because three and three four', 'Third donkey three']}
test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['grams'])
STOPWORDS = {'and', 'does', 'because'}

def rower(x):
    cleanQ = []  
    for i in range(len(x)): cleanQ.append(re.sub(r'[\b\(\)\\\"\'\/\[\]\s+\,\.:\?;]', ' ', x[i]).lower())
    
    splitQ = []
    for row in cleanQ: splitQ.append(row.split())
    splitQ[:] = [[word for word in sub if word not in STOPWORDS] for sub in splitQ]
    splitQ = list(map(' '.join, splitQ))
    print(splitQ)
    
    originQ = []    
    for i in splitQ: 
        originQ.append(PorterStemmer().stem(i))
    print(originQ)
    
rower(test.grams)
```

Which produces this:

```
['first value one two three', 'second value three three four', 'third donkey three']
['first value one two thre', 'second value three three four', 'third donkey thre']
```

The first list shows the sentences before applying the `PorterStemmer()` function. The second list  shows sentences after applying the `PorterStemmer()` function.

As you can see, `PorterStemmer()` trims the word, `three`, into `thre` only when the word is positioned as the last word in a sentence. When the word, `three`, is not the last  word, `three` stays `three`. I can't seem to figure out  why it is doing this. I also worry that if I applied the `rower(x)` function to other sentences, it may produce similar outcomes without me noticing.

How do I prevent `PorterStemmer` from treating the last word differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake here is that you are passing multiple words to the stemmer instead of one word at a time. The entire string (*third donkey three*) is considered one word and the last part is being stemmed.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

test = {'grams': ['First value because one does two THREE', 'Second value because three and three four',
                  'Third donkey three']}
test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['grams'])
STOPWORDS = {'and', 'does', 'because'}

ps = PorterStemmer()

def rower(x):
    cleanQ = []
    for i in range(len(x)): cleanQ.append(re.sub(r'[\b\(\)\\\"\'\/\[\]\s+\,\.:\?;]', ' ', x[i]).lower())

    splitQ = []
    for row in cleanQ: splitQ.append(row.split())
    splitQ = [[word for word in sub if word not in STOPWORDS] for sub in splitQ]
    print('IN:', splitQ)
    originQ = [[ps.stem(word) for word in sent] for sent in splitQ]
    print('OUT:', originQ)


rower(test.grams)
```

Output:

```
IN: [['first', 'value', 'one', 'two', 'three'], ['second', 'value', 'three', 'three', 'four'], ['third', 'donkey', 'three']]
OUT: [['first', 'valu', 'one', 'two', 'three'], ['second', 'valu', 'three', 'three', 'four'], ['third', 'donkey', 'three']]
```

There are good explanations to why stemming leaves out the last 'e' on some words. Consider using a lemmatizer if the output doesn't meet your expectations.

[How to stop NLTK stemmer from removing the trailing “e”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517722/how-to-stop-nltk-stemmer-from-removing-the-trailing-e)

Comment: Change the line to `originQ = [' '.join([ps.stem(word) for word in sent]) for sent in splitQ]`